# Ignore JSON String/Header using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Text file created dynamically and it contains JSON as below

```
Started at 12/06/2017 12:15pm
{"2017-03-19":[{"Hits":1,"Site":"http://xyza.abc/"}]}
Ends at 12/06/2017 12:16pm
```

I need to ignore the "Started at 12/06/2017 12:15pm" and "Ends at 12/06/2017 12:16pm" and take valid JSON, kindly help me out to achieve this using Jquery

Comment: The bits you want to "Ignore" is not valid JSON.Fix the thing which writes invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to remove what's before the start of the json part and what's after its end:

```
text = text.replace(/^[^{]+/, "");
text = text.replace(/[^}]+$/, "");
var parsed = JSON.parse(text);
```